# What is the data sent by the python-dali library for the commands Turnoff, Turnon, stepup, stepdown, and getstatus to the DALI driver?

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip, python, dali

Here is the link to the python-dali library, [python-dali library](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali)

**command description,**
[image: Table describing commands]
The table details are taken by referring -

[DALI COMMANDS 1](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/kl6811/2214047371.html&id=)

[dali2560/dali.txt](https://github.com/cosino/dali2560/blob/master/dali.txt)

[DALI COMMANDS 3](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-0CDBB4BA-5972-4F58-98B2-3F0408F3E10B-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-DA5EBBA5-6A56-4135-AF78-FB1F780EF475)

**Connections overview**

[image: Device connections]

As per my knowledge the connections are shown above in the picture. If it's not accurate, please correct me.

There is a user-interface in the computer for each command above, when user click on any of 5 command buttons above, the python-dali library should analyze the command and should send appropriate signals/binary data to the DALI driver. **I want to print these signals/binary data.**

In my case the DALI driver is Tridonic DALI-USB.

I was able to get binary data for the turn on and turn off using the examples of python-dali library.

Turn on: [async-supplyon](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali/blob/master/examples/async-supplyon.py)

Turn off: [async-supplyoff](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali/blob/master/examples/async-supplyoff.py)

Here is the code snippet.

```
from dali.driver.hid import tridonic

#for the turn off 
turnoff = tridonic._cmd(0x40, 0x00)

#for turnon
turnon = tridonic._cmd(0x40, 0x01)

print("Turnoff data: ", turnoff)
print("\nTurnon data: ", turnon)
```

The output:

```
Turnoff data:  
b'@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Turnon data:  
b'@\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I couldn't figure out how to get binary data for stepup, stepdown, and getstatus commands using python-dali library. Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is purely a software question,  so not really suited for here. Nevertheless, have you looked in general.py for the commands?  My guess (I don’t do python) is _cmd(0x40,0x90) for getStatus.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I went to stack overflow first but could not find dali tag, so posted here. I'll give it a try in it.  
2. Yes, all the commands are in the dali/gear/general.py.  
3. for getStatus the opcode is 0xa0, [dalicommand](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/kl6811/2214047371.html&id=), I am not sure if it's a passed as a parameter to the tridonic._cmd ( tridonic._cmd(0x40, 0xa0) ).  

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The picture with the schematic is a bit misleading. What happens between "the computer" and the "DALI driver" is going to depend on the specifics of your DALI interface. If you have the Tridonic (actually, Lunatone) one, it's some vendor-specific communication over USB HID. Actual DALI communication (as in IEC 62386) then happens between your "DALI interface" and all the "DALI devices" that are connected to the DALI bus (that pair of wires which go from your DALI USB interface).

The question was about sending commands, and the author stated that they looked into the library for individual command bytecodes. That's a part which confuses me further because [`python-dali`](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali) already implements all that is needed. All of the recognized commands are available as classes in modules such as [`dali.gear.general`](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali/blob/master/dali/gear/general.py). Another missing piece is that in DALI, commands usually have a *destination*, i.e., you specify which devices ("control gear") are expected to *execute* a command. The usage then looks for example like this (asyncio loop setup not included, and neither is the driver initialization):

```py
from dali.gear.general import RecallMaxLevel, Off
from dali.address import Broadcast

await dev.send(RecallMaxLevel(Broadcast()))
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await dev.send(Off(Broadcast()))
```

That code would instruct all the DALI *control gear* (LED drivers, etc) to go to their maximal brightness, wait five second, and then turn them all off.

There's even [an example file, `examples/async-flash.py`](https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali/blob/master/examples/async-flash.py) right next to the other examples that the OP linked to. That file contains an expanded version of how these DALI commands are issued.